# Which kind of model can classify daily-photos into meal/person/landscape rather than specific objects?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-classification

I want to classify daily-photos, simply into meal, person, pet, landscape, travelling, etc. I find the image classification models are all based on dataset such as ImageNet2012, and the outputs of these models are object prediction, stray away from my requirement. Which kind of models and datasets can meet my demand? Or is there an method besides neural network, even besides machine learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a large dataset for your classification task what you could simply do is use pretrained model (preferably Resnet50) as a feature extractor and then add a classification layer.

> I find the image classification models are all based on dataset such
> as ImageNet2012, and the outputs of these models are object
> prediction, stray away from my requirement.

Yes, you are right but it's still useful as initial layers learn generic features that apply to variety of problems and then the last classification layer can be more specific to the problem statement

> is there an method besides neural network, even besides machine
> learning?

You could utilize opencv native capabilities but it won't be very scalable for large datasets.

Refer [Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning)